# Crear un número de TextView según elementos de un array

Tags: android

Me encuentro con este problema.

Tengo en un activity un array de Strings. Y lo que no consigo como hacer es que si el array tiene X elementos, se creen en el layout correspondiente esos X TextViews con su correspondiente id y su correspondiente texto.

Ejemplo del activity:

```
private String[] lista = new String[5]
lista[0] = "primera";
lista[1] = "segunda";
lista[2] = "tercera";
lista[3] = "cuarta";
lista[4] = "quinta";
```

Con esos datos lo que quiero hacer es que en el correspondiente layout se genere lo siguiente:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/TextView1"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="10dp" />

<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/TextView2"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextView1" />

<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/TextView3"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextView2" />

<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/TextView4"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextView3" />
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/TextView5"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextView4" />
```

Es decir.. Se crean en el layout un numero de TexView igual al numero de elementos que contiene el array, con su correspondiente id y su correspondiente texto que lo pilla también del array, que en el primero no añada el layout_below pero en los siguientes si y apunte al anterior, para que esté bien alineado.

El problema es que no se si esto se puede hacer y si se puede que es lo que tengo que usar para hacerlo. Supongo que con un simple ejemplo de algo ya hecho ya podría adaptarlo a lo que necesito

Answer (score 2):

Otra opción sería agregar un linear layout, con su id y orientación vertical, dentro del RelativeLayout. En java 
agregarías los textView de acuerdo al tamaño del String array:

```
 LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.tu_layout);

    for(int i = 0; i <lista.length; i++ )
    {
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText(lista[i]);
        //textView.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
        linearLayout.addView(textView);

    Log.d("MIRAAAAAA", String.valueOf(textView.getId()));

        if(textView.getId() ==0) {
            textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            textView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 40);
        }else {
            textView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            textView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        }
    }
```

Si checas el logcat se generan 3 ids de los textViews y oteniendo ese id
los puedes manipular. En lugar de marginBottom puedes aumentar el padding bottom.

Comment: Hice esta opción y funciona, pero no puedo añadir una id por medio de textview.setId() y me faltaría también saber como poder añadir desde el activity la propiedad layout_below

Comment: añadir layout_below para quien? los textviews generados estan uno debajo del otro. Para el id coloca textView.setId(i);

Comment: Solucione lo de layout_below, poniendo el LinearLayout dentro del RelativeLayput y si, se ponen uno de bajo del otro perfecto. Lo que no encuentro ahora es como añadir un margin en la parte inferior. No encuentro propiedad setMarginBottom o algo parecido

Answer (score 1):

Para añadir un TextView desde la activity

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mylayout);

//Esta es la parte que tienes que repetir para cada uno que quieras añadir
//Puedes hacerlo dentro de un bucle que recorra tu array
TextView txt = new TextView(MyClass.this);
txt.setText("texto 1");
linearLayout.addView(txt);
```

Puedes añadir el id con `setId` y modificar ancho con `setLayoutParams`.

Comment: No entiendo la primera linea del codigo, No tengo ningun linearlayout, si no un relativelayout ya creado y su id es "activity_showpage"

Comment: Tienes que crear la vista y añadirla a tu layout con addView, si es un RelativeLayout  sólo tienes que cambiar LinearLayout por RelativeLayout. El id será el que le hayas dado, igual que debes reemplazar el nombre de la clase

Comment: De acuerdo, voy a probar a ver

Comment: Hola, el setId me pide un int, y mis idea son de la sigueinte manera: android:id="@+id/TextViewBienvenida". Como pondría ese id entonces con setId() ?

Comment: Y obviamente me muestra todos los textviews uno encima del otro, ya que no tienen la propiedad layput_below. Ya que no puedo cambiar el id, y luego añadir la propiedad layout_below

Comment: Si van a ir uno debajo de otro es más sencillo si los incluyes dentro de un LinearLayout, el cual puede estar dentro de tu RelativeLayout. Sino, puedes colocarlos modificando las propiedades con setLayoutParams https://android--code.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-relativelayout-below.html. Cuando seteas el id programáticamente el valor es un int, y a través de él puedes acceder al elemento.