# Problema de Posicion de Buttons en Android Studio creados dinamicamente

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Tengo una base de datos y en base a esta creo botones con un nombre, pero no encuentro un método que ponga un botón debajo de otro.
 Se que se puede hacer en el .xml con el layout_below="" pero dinamicamente no me aparece un metodo para posicionarlos uno debajo de otro.

```
public void completaVista()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.mBD.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ManejadorBaseDatos.DatosTabla1.NOMBRE_TABLA,null);
    while (c.moveToNext())
    {
        ScrollView svMaterias = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.svMaterias);
        RelativeLayout rlNuevo = recuadroMateria(c.getString(0)); // me devuelve un Relative Layout con cosas adentro
        svMaterias.addView(rlNuevo);
        ImageButton ibAgrega = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnNewSubject);
        //Algun procedimiento para que ibAgrega este debajo de rlNuevo
    }
}
```

Comment: esta respuesta podría ayudarte, en este caso se crean textViews dinamicamente dentro de un linear Layout y queda uno debajo de otro https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/212479/crear-un-n%C3%BAmero-de-textview-seg%C3%BAn-elementos-de-un-array/212502?noredirect=1#comment396391_212502

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Crear un número de TextView según elementos de un array](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/212479/crear-un-n%C3%BAmero-de-textview-seg%C3%BAn-elementos-de-un-array/212502?noredirect=1#comment396391_212502)

Este link Fue la solucion a la Pregunta! Adaptandolo a botones